# How does /dev/sdX work?

Tags: linux

Sorry if I don't have the correct terminology, I am still somewhat a linux novice.

I have a computer with four hard drives (sda, sdb, sdc & sdd) in it. I am going to add a fifth (sde) which will replace two others (sdb & sdc).

Adding the drive and moving data to it is the easy part for me. What happens when I physically remove the other two disks? Will the labels move down? Will I need to manually edit fstab and fix the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Letters are assigned on the basis of which drive gets enumerated first. The first drive gets `/dev/sda`, the second `/dev/sdb`, etc. If you want to avoid having to modify `/etc/fstab` then you should consider using the filesystem labels or UUIDs instead of the device node.

Comment: Can you expand on filesystem labels and UUIDs? What is the "best practice"?

Comment: @Tom H.: In most places where you can specify a device as `/dev/sdX`, you can also specify it by giving its UUID or (sometimes) the filesystem or volume label. See e.g. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131 for a good explanation. The advantage of using UUID or label is that they don't change when you rearrange the hardware; fs labels can even be kept when you change a drive (because they are assigned manually, and not a property of the hardware).

Comment: Labels can be and UUIDs are assigned to each filesystem that is formatted. They can be viewed with the `blkid` command, and used wherever a device node would be for `mount` (such as in `/etc/fstab`) if preceded by `LABEL=` or `UUID=`.